# In the general form of a straight line $Ax+By+C=0$, what does $C$ actually mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

In the general form of a straight line $Ax+By+C=0$, what does $C$ actually mean? The slope of the straight line seems to affected only by the ratio between A and B. If you take two straight line equations like
$3x+6y+3=0$ and $1x+2y+3=0$.
They form parallel lines but not the same line. The difference in $y$-coordinates of two points on the line at any $x$ value is not equal to $C$. So $C$ is not the $y$ intercept like we saw in $m.x+c=y$ form. Can anyone explain how the general form $Ax+By+C=0$ works. I'm a 14 year old trying to learn straight lines. Thank you. The link of the image of the graph is below.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/d1uzwGqs9jSBx1DN9

Comment: In your original equation, if $~x = 0, ~$ then what is the value of $~y~$? $~$ Similarly, in your original equation, if $~y = 0, ~$ then what is the value of $~x~$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Do some algebra to rewrite
$$
Ax + By + C = 0
$$
in the form
$$
y = mx + c  
$$
by solving it for $y$ in terms of $x$.

Then you can see how $m$ and $c$ depend on $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Yes thank you for the attempt to answer  but what theoretical meaning of c in ax+by+c=0 there has to be right

Comment: No, $C$ by itself in the original equation has no particular theoretical meaning. If you multiply the whole equation by some constant $r$ you have the same line. Only $C=0$ is special: it's a line through the origin.

Comment: oh, if i had a straight line in mind, can I write it's equation in general form

Comment: You can write the equation of a straight line in any form that you find useful. The two in your question are traditional. In the first one the coefficients are not unique.